# Performance of findIndex and possible alternative for large coordinate array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of vectors, `myCoords`, with `x` and `y` coordinates, of size larger than 50,000.

I am looking to find the index value of the vector in `myCoord` having the same coordinate (`x`, `y`) as vector, `myVector`. Note that `myVector` always exists in `myCoords`.

The following line of code returns the index value I am looking for. I was wondering if there is any faster way to obtain the same result. I have to perform this search thousand of time and realized it is significantly slowing down my script.

```
myIndex = myCoords.findIndex(a => a.x === myVector.x && a.y === myVector.y);
```

Comment: you might have to write your own state structure - perhaps some sort of tree.

Comment: Or simply sort the array, then you can use binary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my no-brainer improvement (using deno, but you can use it in any flavor you like):

```js
import { runBenchmarks, bench } from "https://deno.land/std/testing/bench.ts";

bench({
  name: "Array.prototype.findIndex",
  runs: 10_000,
  func(b): void {
    const arr = Array(100_000)
      .fill(null)
      .map(() => ({ x: Math.random(), y: Math.random() } as const));

    const lastItem = arr[arr.length - 1];

    b.start();
    arr.findIndex((item) => item.x === lastItem.x && item.y === lastItem.y);
    b.stop();
  },
});

function findIndex(
  arrX: Float64Array,
  arrY: Float64Array,
  x: number,
  y: number
) {
  const length = arrX.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (arrX[i] === x && arrY[i] === y) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

bench({
  name: "typed array findIndex",
  runs: 10_000,
  func(b): void {
    const arrX = new Float64Array(100_000).map(Math.random);
    const arrY = new Float64Array(100_000).map(Math.random);

    const lastItemX = arrX[arrX.length - 1];
    const lastItemY = arrY[arrY.length - 1];

    b.start();
    findIndex(arrX, arrY, lastItemX, lastItemY);
    b.stop();
  },
});

await runBenchmarks();
```

results:

```
running 2 benchmarks ...
benchmark Array.prototype.findIndex ... 
    10000 runs avg: 1.1294ms
benchmark typed array findIndex ... 
    10000 runs avg: 0.1306ms
benchmark result: DONE. 2 measured; 0 filtered
```

why do we have such improvement here?
well, technically you could go under `O(n)` by using eg. binary search (which has `O(log n)`), but if you don't want to bother just optimize how your code runs by using more performant data structures,

first - don't use closures they are not very performant,

second - notice I've used two typed array here: coordinates are numbers, so let's work on numbers - however I don't know what kind of coordinates you have there so you can optimize that a bit by narrowing the type,

additionally maybe you could try `Object.is` instead of `===` operator, but I'm not sure if there would be any gains